# Finding a maximum value of a $3$-variable polynomial

Tags: calculus, algebra-precalculus, optimization

If 
$$2x+3y+4z=9$$
where $x, y$ and $z$ are positive real numbers, then find the maximum value of 
$$(1+x)^2 (2+y)^3 (4+z)^4\,.$$
I tried to substitute for one variable in the the required relation and used partial derivatives to get the critical point, but I saw this way was difficult. Does it have another way to be solved?

Comment: Do you know lagrange optimization?

Comment: are you sure, that there exists a Maximum?

Comment: no  i dont know it @qbert

Comment: Iam not sure wheather it has or not @Dr.SonnhardGraubner

Comment: Just an observation: If you expand the powers, the linear term is $16x+24y+32z=8(2x+3y+4z)$.

Comment: what qbert mentioned is also known as "Lagrange multipliers method" or "minimisation/maximisation with constraints", or similar. It is usually the standard technique with this type of problems if you wanna look it up

Comment: My guess is that the maximum is at $(12/5,7/5,0)$ which is $\approx  116314$

Answer (score 2):

The coefficients in the constraint coincide with the respective exponents in the target function, which is exploited via
$\,\operatorname{(AM\ge GM)}\,$ to obtain an upper bound for the requested maximum value: 
$$\left[(1+x)^2 (2+y)^3 (4+z)^4\right]^{\frac 19}
\:\le\:\frac 19\big(2(1+x)+3(2+y)+4(4+z)\big)\:=\:3\frac23$$
Note that the inequality is strict iff not all factors $\,1+x, 2+y, 4+z\,$ are equal.

The upper bound equals $\left(3\frac23\right)^9\approx 119796.15$, and it is reached if $\,x=z+3\,$ and $\,y=z+2\,$. But this would imply $\,z=-\frac 13\,$ by the constraint equation, and $\,z\,$ were out of the domain $\mathbb R^+$.

The closest one can do is choosing $z=0$ and aiming at equality in the  remaining factors, i.e., $1+x=2+y\,$. Then the uniquely determined
$$(\,x,y,z\,)\:=\: \left(\frac{12}5,\frac 75, 0\right)$$
maximises the target function to the value $116314.685\,$, as already commented above.